# How to handle the deployment of microservices which listen to message queues

Tags: deployment, microservices, message-queue

I have a microservice that listens on rabbit MQ for background tasks. Assume that each task takes around 1 minute to complete. During deployment when the service is restarted the processing is done twice sometimes because before restart the message is not acknowledged. How do you generally handle this scenario during deployment ??

One solution I can think of is adding a flag in DB and stop consuming messages and flipping the flag once done.

Answer (score 0):

In the stop for deployment case, letting the queue drain before actually stopping the service is likely to be viable:

- Send a signal to the service that it will be redeployed soon
- Service stops consuming messages from MQ
- In-flight tasks are completed and acknowledged
- When all in-flight tasks are completed, service stops (note that this delay may be arbitrarily long)
- Deploy, causing service to begin consuming anew

Setting a flag in a DB which the service is regularly querying would qualify as a signal.

This doesn't, of course, guarantee you that tasks are performed exactly once, unless you can guarantee that, say, an OS crash has the common decency to signal the service that it will be stopped soon and then wait for the service to drain.

So, assuming that it's important that the task get done, you'll still need to think about what happens if it gets done twice.  For that, you generally need to either:

- Have a means of detecting when a task has been performed multiple times and then have some means of compensating for that
- Define (or at least interpret) the task in such a way that doing it twice is effectively the same as doing it once